# Set postgres array field to null from javascript

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I'm updating a field in a postgres database, and I need to set this field to empty that is default NULL for these kind of field.

Here is the query and the field that I  try to set to null is link_target_language

```
UPDATE  links SET link_target_language = null WHERE unique_id = 'b06457b8'
```

null here won't work because any array field requires {}:

```
DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

But if I put {} then the field in the db is {} not NULL as true empty fields.

So how to truly empty an array field in postgress from UPDATE command with js ?

Comment: Add more code please.

Comment: `null` should work... have you received any error ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yes the error I mention above: DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast `null` to the array type:

```
set link_target_language = null::text[]
```